# Subset dataframe based on partial string matching

Tags: r, string, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame containing university names and various names of departments, centres, institutions. I would like to extract all cells containing the string "University" and save it as a vector.

I have tried grep function but as I am quite new to R I did not manage to write a correct function working across multiple columns of the data frame.

This is my example:

```
 V1 = c("asdad","department of x", "University of California",
   "daadasda")
  V2 = c("aadasd","Florence University", "University of Seattle", "NA")
  V3 = c ("aadasd","asdasdasd", "asdasdadads", "fsdfsdfsdf")
  V4 = c ("University of California","Department of g", "asdasd", "sdfsdfsf")

df = as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4))
```

Expected result:

```
Universities: University of California, University of Seattle, Florence University, University of California
```

The data frame has more or less randomly scattered university names, that I would like to extract into a single vector. As I am interested also in the number of occurrences of particular universities, repeating names in the vector are desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the data.frame and `grep` for `University'

```
out <- data.Frame(Universities = grep("University", unlist(df), 
         ignore.case = TRIE.  value = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is exactly the simple solution I was struggling to find. Thank you very much!